# Slamming my stem considerations

Tags: stem, modification, steerer

I want to try a slammed stem but don't want to cut the steerer tube. Do I have to?

Comment: No, just move any spacers from below the stem to on top of it.

Comment: @DavidW That's a valid answer. In fact, it would probably be better not to cut the steerer, in case the OP wants to sell the bike later, or even if they want to change their mind about their position.

Comment: Thanks guys very helpful

Comment: You can also invert the stem from angled up to angled down.

Comment: I think that having an excessively tall chimney might pose a safety risk if u happen to fall over the bars though ..

Answer (score 8):

No, just move any spacers from below the stem to on top of it.

Don't cut the steerer in case you want to sell the bike later, or even if you change your mind later.

Comment: You should cut the steerer if you choose to keep the slammed position, it is a safety risk not to mention looks absurd. Future possible owners are welcome to replace the fork.

Comment: Can you explain the risks?

Comment: @JoeK Please feel free to add an answer, maybe addressing ojs's question.

Comment: @ojs In the event of a crash, that big stack of steerer tube will be perfectly positioned to smash your wedding vegetables. It would be worse if you sat on it...

Comment: It sounds more like an irrational fear suitable for people who come up with expressions like "wedding vegetables". If the risk was serious, racing rules would require top tube pads and cup protectors instead of helmets.

Comment: @ojs In any kind of OTB crash, you're going to fly towards the front of your bike. Some people make sure to avoid buying stems with sharp corners for that exact reason.

Comment: When going over the bars (OTB) the bike pivots about the front axle. That turns the stem out of harm's way. It might be different when smashing into something as high as the front wheel. But in that case one might worry about something a bit more serious than bruises to their gonads. Such as not dying.

Comment: @gschenk Sorry, should have clarified. Yes, a rotational OTB will get the stem out of the way. However, a lateral one (casing a jump, hitting a tree, or really any sort of solid front-end collision) will cause your body to fly directly towards the stem/steerer due to momentum, assuming you can’t jump out of the way.

Comment: Isn't that what @otb meant with irrational fear? A bit like someone worrying that your house might be damaged by an extinction-level asteroid impact. Non-serious injuries that occur only in rare incidents that cause serious injuries. I shouldn't dismiss the risk of internal organ damage when falling with one's thorax or abdomen on the protruding stem cap. A cyclist here died last year to a ruptured spleen after hitting the ends of their handle bars. The stem is another, albeit unlikely, possibility for such blunt trauma.

Comment: A spacer stack of more than 5mm above the stem makes my innards hurt just looking at it...brief episodes of such poor aesthetics due to experimental reasons not withstanding.